# How to use Apps Script Execution API to pull data from a Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api, google-sheets

First, forgive me, I'm relatively new to this stuff. I'm trying to use Javascript on my website to pull data from one of my Google Sheets (which I don't want to publish or make publicly available, etc.). I'm currently trying to use the Apps Script Execution API to do this.

Basically, I want to pull specific apps script functions (which return values from the specific Google sheet) and store the results of these functions in variables in my website's Javascript, which I can then manipulate further with additional Javascript on my webpage.

Again, please forgive me if I said something wrong or stupid. But for what I'm trying to achieve, what's the best way to go about this?

Comment: thats not what that api is for, unless you want to force all users to be logged in with a google account and approve permissions. use a published content Service instead. look more at the documentation and show us your attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/api), you should have single `scripts` resource that has a single method, `run`, that makes calls to specific Apps Script functions. Your `run` method should have the [ID of the script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution/rest/v1/scripts/run#path-parameters), the [name of the function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution/rest/v1/scripts/run#request-body) within the script to execute, and the [list of parameters](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution/rest/v1/scripts/run#response-body) the function requires.

You can use [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/) to access and modify data from your Google Sheets.

> To retrieve the data from the spreadsheet, you must get access to the spreadsheet where the data is stored, get the range in the spreadsheet that holds the data, and then get the values of the cells. Apps Script facilitates access to the data by reading structured data in the spreadsheet and creating JavaScript objects for them.

This [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets#get_started) shows example on how to retrieve and log the product names and product numbers.

```
function logProductInfo() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    Logger.log('Product name: ' + data[i][0]);
    Logger.log('Product number: ' + data[i][1]);
  }
}
```

Check this [example](https://github.com/ChrisRisner/chrisrisner.github.io/blob/c71cba954b5dbe786e811b8cfa0231804540d917/_posts/2015-10-06-Google-Apps-Execution-API.markdown) from GitHub. It's an Apps Script which could pull data out of Sheets like weekly, monthly, and daily budget as well as update that data.

Comment: while the answer is technically ok, the o.p. should not use execution api for this scenario.